# Is there any API for checking a Status of a given Order with Realex Payments?

Tags: realex-payments-api

I am wanting to integrate Realex for my upcoming E-Commerce website. Imagine a scenario as mentioned below:

1. Customer came to the site, added the products to the Cart and moved ahead to payments.
2. Now, Customer entered his details on the payment page, and clicked
   on the “Pay Now” button.
3. Imagine below given possible issues (Bad transactions) which might
   occur and I am trying to overcome the same:

   A.    The request was processed successfully by Realex, and while redirecting to my Server URL there was a Network glitch due to which the Redirection failed.

   B.    The request was processed successfully by Realex, and as it was redirecting there was an Issue with my Server side (let’s suppose some Code related issue).

Now, in the both above mentioned scenarios I need to understand, if there is any way wherein I can check the given Order’s status without manually doing so?

i.e. Is there any Status check API which can provide me the status of the Order, i.e. if it was processed successfully and I might go ahead with the Order or either go ahead for the Refund to the given Customer?

Comment: I'm also looking for this.

Found out, that other payment gateways provide such Status Check API calls, see:

https://www.datatrans.ch/showcase/status-request/xml-status-request

Comment: Well @zeek most of the payment gateways do. But since the Client is stuck on this one I don't have any other options on doing other Payment gateways.